# Finding all docs that match minimum amount of array values

Tags: mongodb, go

First time I am writing MongoDB query and managed up to certain point for now but stuck at the moment. I looked into the *match* property but not sure if it is relevant.

The query below will return all the `user` documents that contain *at least one* given `role`.

```
roles := []string{"admin", "super_admin", "manager", "student"}

a.db.Collection("users").Find(ctx, bson.M{"roles": bson.M{"$in": roles}})

// db.users.find({roles: { $in: ["admin", "super_admin", "manager", "student"] }})
```

What I need now is that, specify the minimum matching criteria. For example, the user document must match at least 2 given roles (*doesn't matter which ones they are*). I will need to use something like `EQ, GTE, GT, LT, LTE` operators.

**Update**

It is ok to just handle minimum match so happy to ignore all the listed operators above.

Comment: what is the type of roles field in document? is it array and having multiple roles?

Comment: That's correct, it is an array with string values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure there are any other easy way to achieve this, you can use aggregation operators in find if you are using MongoDB v4.4 or you can use `aggregate()`, I don't know about `go` syntax but I can do it in MongoDB driver query,

- `$reduce` to iterate loop of roles array, se initial value to 0, check condition if current role is in you input role then add one in initial value otherwise return existing initial value,
- check expression with `$gte` that return number is greater than 2

```
db.users.find({
  $expr: {
    $gte: [
      {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$roles",
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {
            $cond: [
              { $in: [$$this", ["admin","super_admin","manager","student"]] },
              { $add: ["$$value", 1] },
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      2 // input your number
    ]
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/T4LUscnGWzm)

---

**Using aggregate():**
[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qY5YLEcjosT)

Comment: Thank you for this. Both works fine. Now I have to turn them into Go query which should be fun!

Answer (score 0):

Follows up to accepted answer, this is the Go version of it. Just for those who might need some reference.

```golang
    filter := bson.M{
        "$expr": bson.M{
            "$gte": []interface{}{
                bson.M{
                    "$reduce": bson.M{
                        "input":        "$roles",
                        "initialValue": 0,
                        "in": bson.M{
                            "$cond": []interface{}{
                                bson.M{
                                    "$in": []interface{}{
                                        "$$this",
                                        roles, // This is your []string slice
                                    },
                                },
                                bson.M{
                                    "$add": []interface{}{
                                        "$$value",
                                        1,
                                    },
                                },
                                "$$value",
                            },
                        },
                    },
                },
                minMatch, // This is the limit
            },
        },
    }
```